# Problems using Go App Engine behind a proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, go, polymer

I'm trying to run the example application hosted at: https://github.com/googlesamples/cloud-polymer-go, but when running it behind a proxy, I get the following errors:

```
$ goapp serve dispatch.yaml frontend/app.yaml backend/app.yaml
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,461 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,526 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:59441
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,527 dispatcher.py:185] Starting dispatcher running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,529 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "frontend" running at: http://localhost:8081
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,534 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8082
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:19,534 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:23,859 module.py:786] frontend: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:23,870 module.py:786] frontend: "GET /elements/post-list.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:24,377 module.py:786] frontend: "GET /elements/post-service.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:24,377 module.py:786] frontend: "GET /elements/post-form.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-10-13 13:04:24,377 module.py:786] frontend: "GET /elements/post-card.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
WARNING  2015-10-13 13:04:26,344 dispatcher.py:762] Skipping dispatch.yaml rules because /_ah/api/static/proxy.html is not a dispatchable path.
socket.error 101
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2117, in respond
    for chunk in response:
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 121, in __call__
    yield self.dispatch(request, start_response)
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 138, in dispatch
    start_response)
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 172, in dispatch_non_api_requests
    return dispatch_function(request, start_response)
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 212, in handle_api_static_request
    response, body = discovery_api.get_static_file(request.relative_url)
  File "/home/robert/applib/appEngine/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/discovery_api_proxy.py", line 113, in get_static_file
    connection.request('GET', path, None, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1178, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

The variables:

```
$ echo $http_proxy 
http://asusis-isa2.personal.com.py:8080/
$ echo $https_proxy 
http://asusis-isa2.personal.com.py:8080/
```

Are correctly set.

I works with a direct Internet connection.

I'm under Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Looks like there is a defect in the SDK around using a proxy with URLFetch.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544

Try setting the uppercase versions of those environment variables, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`. The [`gcloud` launcher](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app#Using_an_HTTP_proxy) requires them that way so I assume `goapp` does as well.

> **Using an HTTP proxy**
>
> If you are running gcloud preview app behind an HTTP proxy, you must
>   tell gcloud preview app the name of the proxy. To set an HTTP proxy
>   for gcloud preview app, set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment
>   variables. Note that you must specify the full path for the app.yaml
>   file.
>
> Using Windows (in Command Prompt):
>
> ```
> $ set HTTP_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
> $ set HTTPS_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
> $ gcloud preview app deploy DIRECTORY/app.yaml
> ```
>
> Using the command line in Mac OS X (in Terminal) or Linux:
>
> ```
> $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://cache.mycompany.com:3128"
> $ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://cache.mycompany.com:3128"
> $ gcloud preview app deploy DIRECTORY/app.yaml
> ```

Comment: I'm not familiar with gcloud. I'm just using goapp. I tried putting them uppercase, but it does not work either.

Comment: gcloud is the unified tooling for deploying app engine applications so it shares a lot of the same infrastructure and ideas as the app engine sdk.

Comment: According to https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ it should respect HTTP_PROXY based on your current `env`. Stupid question but are those environment variables set in the env of the user that you are running `goapp serve` as?

Comment: Yes, they are.  /* comments must be 15 chars long, so I'll fill this one with a comment. */

Comment: If it still isn't working then it may be a bug and you can report it here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues

Comment: @chila See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544 I have updated my answer to also include this bug report.